# Como instalar o node.js na sua versão mais recente(12.x) pelo terminal do ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, instalador

Estou tentando instalar o nodeJS no meu Linux.Porém, mesmo colocando os códigos para a versão 12.x:

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

O terminal apenas instala a versão 8.10.
Quando executo o comando `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential`, ele executa os processos e no final funciona:

```
nodejs is already the newest version (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4).
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 22 não atualizados.
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu instalo usando [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), até porque o ***apt-get*** nem sempre tem a versão instavel e mais atual.

Primeiro no terminal instale o pacote usando ***curl*** ou ***wget***, basta executar um dos comandos:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash

wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

Verifique se sua instalação está correta:

```
command -v nvm
```

Obs: É interssante executar isto após fechar e abrir um novo terminal.

Liste as versões do node:

```
nvm ls-remote
```

Instale a versão que deseja:

```
nvm install 10.16.3
```

Eu coloquei a versão 10.16.3 porque é a versão mais instavel segundo a [documentação do nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Answer (score 1):

Cara tenta este comando:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Segunda opção:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install node --channel=12/stable --classic
```

Conforme [link](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-node-js-10-11-12-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-via-apt-and-snap/)